# HTTP-Invoke URL by Windows Task Scheduler (schtasks.exe)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, http, cron, task-scheduler

I'd like to send `HTTP` requests using the Windows Task Scheduler. In `UNIX` cron jobs, I can do that using

```
wget http://www.google.com -O /dev/null
```

How to do the same on a Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a [windows version of wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/).  Create a batch file, if you need more processing:

```
@echo off
wget http://www.google.com -O nul
rem do something else, if needed
```

In your Task, simply call this batch file.

Comment: thanks, no native tool that can do the same?

Comment: @cheeesus: PowerShell can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973880/download-url-content